# Very slow networked file Read speed?

Tags: windows, file, networking, vb6

I have a binary file with file size 345 KB.
I am trying to read the file in VB6 line by line into string array with length of 26 (For loading to my data table).
The sample code is as below:

```
Dim fn1 As Integer
Dim FileStringArray(26) As String
fn1 = FreeFile
Open filepath For Binary As #fn1
    Do While EOF(fn1) = False
        Get fn1, , FileStringArray
        For i = 0 To 25
            'Do something with FileStringArray(i)
        Next                
    Loop
Close fn1
```

This works perfectly in local PC. The 345 KB file can be read within 1 second. Same speed is also expected in case of network with 1 Gbps. When I test the file open through network, the file is opening fast same as local path.

But, in some computers, even if the network speed is 1Gbps (Practical speed is 850 Mbps when tested by copying 102MB & 1GB files), the file takes about 20 seconds to read. For each GET line with array size of 26, it takes about 0.015 seconds (That is 66 lines per seconds). In normal speed, it takes just 0.125 seconds for entire file of 1507 lines.

When I test with different computers in my network, I found that for some computers, it took nearly 20 seconds for the first time and for next time it was proper. But, some computers do not show this behavior. One computer is constantly taking 22 seconds even if its network is 1 Gbps even when there is no other data transfer. This problem is found in some of my customer’s computers.

I have tried to read the file all at once by setting array size to file length & that also shows same result. Also, I have tried to open the file using Line input method & it was faster than binary GET. But, comparing to other computers, it is slower with same difference as binary file.

The text file source computer specification is Intel core i7 with 8 GB of RAM, Windows 10 Pro 64 bit connected to 1Gbps network. I have other computers with same and lower configuration & file read speed was proper in all other computers.

If I open the text file in that PC locally, it is proper. If I open the file in same PC through UNC, it takes about 1.9 Seconds.
In VB.Net, for reading in same code above, it takes 0.031 second in normal computer and 1.51 second in problem computer.

Comment: I suspect the problem is not that the file is coming slowly across the network but that some other lengthy  process is taking place every time you read a line

Comment: Virus scanners?  Proxy latency?  Subnet routing?

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't really huge, you can speed up the reads by grabbing the contents in one large blob, then splitting it apart into its component lines in memory.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
' Read an entire text file into memory in one shot, for speed (requires LOF * 2 available memory)

  Dim FileName As String, Handle As Integer, Blob As String, Lines() As String

  FileName = InputBox("Enter file name")    ' prompt the user for the file name
  If FileName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub  ' Cancel

  If Len(Dir(FileName)) = 0 Then    ' first check for existance of file, because "Open For Binary" will create it
    MsgBox "Unable to open file '" & FileName & "' - file does not exist", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error Resume Next              ' OK, it exists, so try to open the file
  Handle = FreeFile
  Open FileName For Binary As #Handle
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to open file '" & FileName & "' - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  Blob = Space(LOF(Handle))         ' pre-allocate the string to the correct size
  Get #Handle, , Blob               ' read the whole file in one shot
  Close #Handle

  Lines = Split(Blob, vbCrLf)
  If UBound(Lines) < 0 Then
    MsgBox "The file is empty."
  Else
    MsgBox "The file contains " & CStr(UBound(Lines) + 1) & " lines of text."
  End If

' Perform other processing here

End Sub
```

I tried this with the full text of "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes" ( about 576k) over a WiFi network, and the read took less than two seconds.

For the OP's application, the  `Split()`  call would be replaced with a simple loop that copied sections of the  `Blob`  string into a (pre-dimensioned) string array, probably using the  `Mid()`  function.

~~
Mark Moulding